# Send a message to a user with the Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to send a message to a user, but it's not working. Any idea why?

```
<?php 

  $app_id = '####';
  $app_secret = '###';

  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . $app_id .
    "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
    "&grant_type=client_credentials";

  $app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $user_id = '###';

  $apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    $user_id .
    "/apprequests?message='INSERT_UT8_STRING_MSG'" . 
    "&data='INSERT_STRING_DATA'&"  .   
    $app_access_token . "&method=post";

  $result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
  echo "Request id number: ". $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the not the way to send post request

```
$apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    $user_id .
    "/apprequests?message='INSERT_UT8_STRING_MSG'" . 
    "&data='INSERT_STRING_DATA'&"  .   
    $app_access_token . "&method=post";
```

You should use php curl to send post request or [check this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#108309)